# App engine not deploying Python app when new version is pushed to github

Tags: python, google-app-engine, github

I have an app that is connected to a github repository with a pipeline defined and set to `Deploy source only (Python, PHP)`.  When I push an update to the master branch, I can see the updated code in the app engine console under the source code / browse page so I know the app and repo are connected and receiving the update, but the deployment is not triggering.  When I look at the source code / releases page of the console the area that would list each deployment is blank.  There are no errors being reported that I can see.

I have another app in the same app engine account connected to the same github user account but a different repository that has successfully deployed many times.  I can not see any difference between the working and non-working apps / repositories in the configuration.

Is there any way to trouble shoot such an issue?

Comment: After submitting a problem report to Google about this issue, they were able to duplicate the problem and then asked me try it again and it worked.  No explanation as to why it did not work.